# Would you accept work in Smalltalk 2017?

Tags: career-development

My employer wants me to work in Smalltalk programming after providing training.
What are the pros and cons of doing so? Would working in Smalltalk make me unemployable in the future?

I have 6.5 years of experience in legacy application maintenance programming: VB6, PowerBuilder, Crystal Reports, few years in C#, and ASP.NET. I also know PHP, MySql, .NET MVC, Web API, and AngularJS.

I have to look for other options, but as of now Smalltalk is the option put forth by my employer because our client wants an application to be maintained.
Also, I saw the Stack Overflow survey which shows 2nd popular language is Smalltalk.

I wanted to be a web developer, but I can be satisfied if I work in programming rather than management.

Comment: this is going to be closed, but you should also consider letting us know what you program in. Generally, working on something, whatever it is, doesn't make you unemployable. Do you want to do it is the better question.

Comment: @bharal No... for instance, knowledge with Windows Mobile would make you useless.

Comment: But if you're an experience programmer, you don't have a problem. You have enough experience be competitive in the market.

Comment: What other options do you have?

Comment: **(A)** I take it you mean that your manager will provide you training in Smalltalk, rather than you providing the training. **(B)** Could you provide a link to the URL of the Stack Overflow survey which you read?

Comment: This is the developer survey link. https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017

Answer (score 2):

Your added background shows that you are strongly placed to maintain older systems written with older technology. Adding Smalltalk to that mix isn't going to weaken your position. It clearly makes you more valuable to your current employer. It might not make you attractive to some hot, high-velocity startup building on the framework of the week, but when that startup sees VB6, Crystal Reports, PHP etc they are going to think of you as a legacy developer anyway, so adding Smalltalk has no real impact on them.

In the longer term bigger picture, every language you learn gives you a chance at insight and a different way of thinking that will help you in all the other things you do. Certain things that are idiomatically easy in Smalltalk are genuinely useful and worth taking the time to code in other languages. You can make this an experience that helps your career. And understanding business needs and being prepared to do something to help a client is also a very valuable lesson.

If you don't think this employer will ever lead you to your web programming destination, there's nothing wrong with looking for a job that will. But while you're in this job, why not be amazing at it and learn all you possibly can? You may discover client-side programming is not just a legacy technique after all.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I feel I should be learning more and work in latest/web technologies.But during my initial days of career I was compelled to work in legacy even though I am interested in other. Now if I try to move to higher end tech the companies/clients look for relevant work experience which I dont have. For this reason I have to again convince myself and choose legacy again. But in longer run I wont be competitive at all. This is how I feel.

Comment: So that's a different question: **how can I be seen as a valuable candidate for web developer jobs when I don't have significant experience with current web development techniques?** Do you think your employer has a project available with current web techniques and is just choosing not to put you on it? I doubt it. How to get your web experience and what to do when assigned projects at your current employer are (from what I can see) issues with no overlap.

Comment: To explain more about my employer, there are more people in indian IT service based company. We don't have much of a choice to select the technology.smalltalk is the i have now. I can look further into other projects for better scope but again I had my doubts whether small talk is good to invest my time or I should look further.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from investing personal time into learning more 'current' techniques.